# Image overflow onmobile Browsers

Tags: html, image, mobile

I got a html code with an image. The image is very wide so i integrated a "overflow:hidden;" to my css to theimage and even to the whole body. It works on every Desktop Browser, but
dont work e.g. with Chrome on a Android OS.

It seems that the mobile browser is looking for the object with the highest width and scales his zoom to have this width on 100% of the screen.

Does anybody know this problem?

Thx for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Tweak the width and initial-scale values of your [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), which is inside `<head>`, this is an example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: this changed something, but no the viewport is just at the very right

Answer (score -1):

do you need to have it as an image?
you could use it as a background-image, or place it inside a div and give that div the overflow:hidden attribute

Comment: it is already inside a div with overflow hidden, even body has overflow hidden